# Changing some letters in entry's uri before save it

Tags: plugin-development, craft2

I need to replace some characters in my entry's URI because we have some letters which do not exist in English like "ş" or "ç". It is a problem for SEO and we have to change each time manually. I tried something with `entries.onBeforeSaveEntry` but I couldn't solve the problem. I'm confused with getting URI and set the new URI. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think you may have to use the "After save entry" event to change a URI.

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this, maybe any of you will use with different types of it.

```
craft()->on('entries.onBeforeSaveEntry', function(Event $event) {
  $entry = $event->params['entry'];
  $turkishCharacters = ['ı', 'ü', 'ö', 'ş', 'ç', 'ğ'];
  $englishCharacters = ['i', 'u', 'o', 's', 'c', 'g'];

  $entrySlug = $entry->slug;
  $entrySlug = str_replace($turkishCharacters, $englishCharacters, $entrySlug);     
  $entry->slug = $entrySlug;
});
```